# truncating ros time

Tags: ros, tf2, rostime, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Is there anyway i could truncate the ros time value to certain length, lets say i need the time value to be only up to a certain decimal points

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305269/truncating-ros-time/) by [lahiruherath](https://answers.ros.org/users/32349/lahiruherath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2018-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-09**:
So you want to reduce the precision of timestamps by truncating them?

If so, could I ask you for a topic title change? Right now it seems like you're asking about the precision of rostime and/or ROS timestamps. But that is not actually the case.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-09**:
And to avoid an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info/): can you describe why you'd want to do this?

**Comment by [lahiruherath](https://answers.ros.org/users/32349/lahiruherath/) on 2018-10-09**:
Hi,
I want to stop tf from looking into the exact time stamp to find a transform

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-09**:
And why do you want to do that? What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll jump in here because I think exactly how the TF system works needs to be clarified.

TF doesn't look for a transform with exactly the right time stamp when you lookup a transform, it almost always interpolates the two nearest TF samples. It can also extrapolate into the future a short time based on previous data but this is not recommended.

Are you getting the `Lookup would require extrapolation at time X` error? In this case adding a timeout Duration to the [lookupTransform](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1Buffer.html#acabbd72cae8f49fb3b6ede3be7e34c55) call would be the preferred method of solving this.

But as @gvdhoorn says, it would be helpful to know the actual problem you're trying to solve before we can suggest the best solution for you.

**Update:**

Thanks for clarifying the problem you're trying to solve, I see two possible solutions you can look into.

1. Use message filters to synchronise the messages as @tfoote has suggested
2. You could request the most recent data when looking up the transform by setting the time to zero. This achieves exactly what you suggested initially via a different mechanism.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lahiruherath](https://answers.ros.org/users/32349/lahiruherath/) on 2018-10-09**:
Hi Peter,

I know this, lemme explain my specific problem.

I have depth image from a sensor which i actually get using a another API and I convert to a ROS message. The odometry is also taken similarly and tf is broadcasted, I assign the time stamps myself.
They are running on two separate threads.

**Comment by [lahiruherath](https://answers.ros.org/users/32349/lahiruherath/) on 2018-10-09**:
The time stamps do not match because of this, I convert the depth to PCL and i need to transform it to another frame. The lookup gives an error. I cannot hang my conversion until a transform is taken. I just need to find a way to transform it in some viable rate. My sensors run on 15-25 Hz

**Comment by [lahiruherath](https://answers.ros.org/users/32349/lahiruherath/) on 2018-10-09**:
So a time stamp in this range is okay for me. So i thought i would cap the initial stamp at some decimal place. Don't know whether it is viable or possible. Or maybe I'm just shooting in some uselss direction.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-10-09**:
From your use case you should not be truncating your timestamps. What you're trying to do is basically extrapolate into the future by a small bit, but rounding all your timestamps. This has been explored many times and almost always leads to unintended consequences.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-10-09**:
You cannot apply a transform until the data is available. It can actually make a difference when during the 40ms between a 25Hz signal is processed. I'd strongly recommend that you look at using a Message Filter in your pipeline to hold the data for the few milliseconds until the data is available.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-10-09**:
http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Using%20stamped%20datatypes%20with%20tf2%3A%3AMessageFilter

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-10**:
And this was exactly why I asked about the `xy-problem`.

**Comment by [lahiruherath](https://answers.ros.org/users/32349/lahiruherath/) on 2018-10-10**:
@tfoote, Thanks didn't know about this message filter. Another small question what's your advice use tf since pcl_ros still has tf in its conversions, or shift to tf2?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-10-10**:
You should use tf2. tf has been deprecated for years and is used under the hood in tf.